# Interpreting $H^n(BG,\mathbb Z)$ when $G$ is an infinite discrete group

Tags: group-cohomology, gap

Suppose $G$ is a two-dimensional space group, for example a semidirect product of $\mathbb Z^2$ with a crystallographic point group such as $\mathbb Z_2$, where the action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on $\mathbb Z^2$ corresponds to reflection about the origin. I am trying to understand the object $H^n(BG,\mathbb Z)$. In particular, I would like to equate this to something that can be computed with group cohomology functions from GAP. I have read that for compact Lie groups, one can say that $H^n(BG, \mathbb Z) \cong H^{n}_B(G,\mathbb Z)$ where $H^*_B$ is the Borel group cohomology. Therefore,

1) Can a similar statement be made for space groups, which are infinite discrete?

2) Naively using the GAP function *GroupCohomology(G,n)* seems to give incorrect results for particular space groups. Should I be computing something different?

Comment: It is certainly true that for infinite discrete groups $G$, the group cohomology ring $\text{Ext}^*_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ is the same as the singular cohomology of the classifying space $BG$.  But I don't know anything about what GAP can do with that.

Comment: I removed the tag "crystalline cohomology".  That refers to something completely different.

Comment: I believe GroupCohomology(G,n) should be correct. I have recent experience of using GAP to compute group cohomology of space groups to classify crystalline SPT phases (in physics); we can discuss in chat (as I'm not sure it's on-topic for MO): https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79729/gap-for-space-groups